# I'm new to coding, can I code a command block into a .json datapack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I started coding very recently [.json to be exact] and I'm trying to create a few custom things for me and my friends. But one of the things I want to do requires me to run a command from Minecraft,
[To be exact the command "/time add 5"]
But how would I code it in so that Minecraft will run that command..?

Comment: "Coding" is an extremely broad term, wdym specifically by "coding"

Answer (score 1):

You can use so called [Minecraft Functions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Function_(Java_Edition)) an attach them to either the minecraft:tick or minecraft:load [Function Tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag).

Functions can be run using the `/function functionnamehere`-command.